# xpath advanced expression needed

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following code and I'm trying to isolate the radio buttons into two xpath expressions so I can click on them in nightwatch for QA.

Please keep in mind this page in particular has many other radio buttons so the expression needs to be specific to this.  Also the reactid's are dynamic and change so can't hook into that.  Much appreciated

```
<div class="form-group" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0">
<label class="control-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$label">
<span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$label.1" style="">Able to change e-mail</span>
</label>
<div class="wrapper" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper" style="">
    <input type="radio" name="allow_change_email" checked="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:0" style="">
    <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:1" style=""> Allow</span>
    <br data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:2">
    <input type="radio" name="allow_change_email" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:3" style="">
    <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:4" style=""> Disable</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by isolate here ... do you want click on Allow or Disable ..

Comment: If you only show a small snippet of the HTML document, nobody can tell you what the most appropriate XPath expression would be. The usefulness of XPath expressions depends very much on the document context. As it is now, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

**This is one possible XPath :** (formatted for readability)

```
//label[span='Able to change e-mail']
 /following-sibling::div[1]
 /input[@type='radio' and following-sibling::span[1][normalize-space()='Allow']]
```

**explanation :**

- **`//label[span='Able to change e-mail']`** : find `label` element where child `span` content equals `"Able to change e-mail"`
- **`/following-sibling::div[1]`** : from such `label`, find the nearest following sibling `div` element
- **`/input[@type='radio' and following-sibling::span[1][normalize-space()='Allow']]`** : from such `div`, return `input` element where `type` attribute equals `"radio"` and the nearest following sibling `span` equals `"Allow"`

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b99ea9908947a5b4bb1d16228b8d5f7c)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<input checked="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:0" name="allow_change_email" style="" type="radio"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have valid XML.

If you manage to correct it you can use this:

```
//input[@type='radio']
```

'Corrected' XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<div class="form-group" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0">
 <label class="control-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$label">
   <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$label.1" style="">Able to change e-mail</span>
 </label>
 <div class="wrapper" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper" style="">
   <input type="radio" name="allow_change_email" checked="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:0" style="" />
   <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:1" style=""> Allow</span>
   <br data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:2" />
   <input type="radio" name="allow_change_email" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:3" style="" />
   <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.0.0.$wrapper.0:4" style=""> Disable</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is part of a HTML page with thousands of other elements and the xpath is used with nightwatchjs.org to do some qa

Comment: That may be but it is still invalid XML....my parser barfed on it.   If you can incorporate 3rd party DLL's in your environment, you would be much better off with HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

For Allow:-

```
//div[@class='wrapper']/input[1][@type='radio']
```

For Disable:-

```
//div[@class='wrapper']/input[2][@type='radio']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for anyone else that may be in the same situation.

```
//*[text()="Able to change email"]/following::span[text()= " Allow"][1]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

Comment: Nobody knows why and if this is the best XPath expression in your situation, because you haven't shown much of the document and have not explained which parts of the documents are prone to changes.